# Autostart command to have gpodder (GUI) start on every system start & update podcasts

Tags: gpodder

I am aware there is a gpodder extension that searches for new podcast on every startup of the program, but since my podcast subscription list is quite long that makes the program a bit cumbersome to use when I just want to add a new podcast URL or check something else.

I would like a command that I can add to the startup applications that launches the gpodder gui, and has it scan for new podcasts.

I am aware of gpo -> update -> download, but I would like to have the graphical interface do that.

Comment: Did you try adding `/usr/bin/gpo update && /usr/bin/gpo download` to your `.profile`?

Comment: I am aware of that, but that's command line only, I believe. I would like the GUI gpodder to launch and update automatically.